# jmeter for capturing system generated dynamic values

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter for a real estate application when I am selecting a plot it is generating a dynamic value like this 1305003402565. It is incrementing like this 1305003280751 per request to request I need to capture this value and I am not able to find it in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to force your application to show the dynamic value in the source code by requesting the page as a GET (instead of POST).  Then, using Tree View, copy the source into your favorite regular expression extractor to write your regex to extract the value.